# Section based routing in nextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

We are about to build a new react based frontend layer for a large and complex news website. We are considering using nextJS, but one thing that puzzles me is the built-in file based routing in nextJS. In our website, content always belong to a section and sections are represented by the path in the URL.

Example:

- /regions/region-A
- /regions/region-B

…

- /area-of-expertise/tax
- /area-of-expertise/macro-economics

…

The sections (regions, region-A, region-B, area-of-expertise, tax and macro-economics) are created in our CMS and there could be various type of content in every section.

The “tax”-section (that is a subsection of “area-of-expertise”) could contain different types of content, e.g., regular news articles and reports. The visual representation of a news article and a report is different, but there is no way to tell the difference between them by just looking at the URL. Example:

- /area-of-expertise/tax/title-of-news-article_id.html
- /area-of-expertise/tax/title-of-report_id.html

Considering the above, would you still consider nextJS to be a good alternative for us? Would you recommend using another routing library?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if NextJS is the best framework for your needs, but you may want to look into [per-page layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts), which would allow each individual page to optionally specify it's layout.

You'd define a `NewsArticleLayout` and a `ReportLayout`, then have your components for each route define a `getLayout` function.

For example, `/area-of-expertise/tax/title-of-report_id.html` could look something like this:

```js
import Layout from '../../../components/layouts/Layout';
import ReportLayout from '../../../components/layouts/ReportLayout';

export default function Page() {
  return (
    /** Report content goes here */
  )
}

Page.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <ReportLayout>{page}</ReportLayout>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```